# No Hibernate Session bound to thread exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have Hibernate 3.6.0.Final and Spring 3.0.0.RELEASE

I get "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here"

If I add the thread specification back in, I get "saveOrUpdate is not valid without active transaction"

Any ideas?

The spring-config.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.maxheapsize" />

<bean id="dataSource"
         class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
         destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:jsf2demo"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="sampleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sampleDataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.maxheapsize.jsf2demo.Book</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</prop-->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <!-- prop key="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop-->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="sampleDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>
            jdbc:hsqldb:file:/spring/db/springdb;SHUTDOWN=true
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sampleSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="daoTxTemplate" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="create*">
                PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
            </prop>
            <prop key="get*">
                PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sampleSessionFactory"/>
    <property name="singleSession" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="nameDao" parent="daoTxTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.maxheapsize.dao.NameDao">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sampleSessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and the DAO:

```
public class NameDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Name> getAll() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Name> names = (List<Name>)session.createQuery("from Name").list();
        return names;
    }

    //@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    @Transactional
    public void save(Name name){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(name);
        session.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be unrelated but try with Spring 3.0.5.

Comment: Don't just post the exception messages, post the stack traces as well, there's useful information in there.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception coming from? Where is the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Spring version isn't your issue.

I'd also recommend not annotating your DAO with transactions.  Those belong on a service tier that has the DAO injected in.  That's where the session comes in as well: open the session for the use case, execute it, close the transaction, clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enable [annotation driven transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative). In the link, search for `tx:advice`.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<beans xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
```

and

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

to your context file.

Comment: the tx namespace isn't recognized

Comment: suucceeded to add but now i get an error:  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.maxheapsize.dao.NameDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Your bean implements an interface? You should autowire the interface and not the bean. It happens since your bean now was wrapped with proxy that implements the same interface, but it is not instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the property in the hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
thread
```

Answer (score 0):

add taransaction manager :

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    id="hibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
```

and annotate all ur DAO classes with @Transactional